# Object null reference exception on generic ServiceStackController in ServiceStack Mvc

Tags: servicestack

In ServiceStack this line is not correct.

userSession = this.Cache.Get(SessionKey); (Line:28)

**Cache is null when this code is called.**

My production site is broken now.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big mistake of me. This code

```
container.Register(new MemoryCacheClient());
```

MUST CALL BEFORE

```
    Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new OzUserSession(),
        new IAuthProvider[] {
            new OzCredentialsAuthProvider(appSettings)
        }));
```

But also ServiceStackController throw meaningful exception ( Cache could not resolved) because It has dependency to cache!